# Cannot find Bootstrap.groovy or Datasource.groovy files in grails project

Tags: grails

I'm doing [this](https://grails.org/wiki/Quick%20Start) tutorial. It says `the Grails BootStrap class, which you can find in grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy`

But alas, it is not there:

```
./grails-app
+--conf
|    +--spring/
|    +--application.yml
|    +--logback.groovy
```

The tutorial also says `all new Grails applications include the file grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`. But alas, this is not true either.

If I create the files manually, they do not actually do anything. I am using Grails v3.1.10, Groovy v2.4.7, and JVM v1.7.0_101. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that page is quite dated and not correct for Grails 3+.

You can find `BootStrap.groovy` under `grails-app/init`, and the settings that were specified in `DataSource.groovy` are now with the rest of the config settings in `application.yml` (or `application.groovy` if you create it).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your project is imported from somewhich is lack of these files. You need create you project, these files will be created automatically.